gradle error Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'
Android studio: Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2
JDK: 17.0.11
gradle version; 8.7
gradle plugin version: 8.5.2
these are my settings
i dont know what wrong with android studio. it can't even sync and build its own new projects. such a shame.
stack overflow people please someone help me. I chacked all compatibility matrixes and tested a ton of versions to make it but nothing was helpful.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'jc2'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find bundletool-1.16.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.16.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.16.0/bundletool-1.16.0.jar
   > Could not find core-proto-0.0.9-alpha02.jar (com.google.testing.platform:core-proto:0.0.9-alpha02).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/testing/platform/core-proto/0.0.9-alpha02/core-proto-0.0.9-alpha02.jar

